# Distance between Bhur lok (Earth) and Indra lok?

Tags: lokas, astronomy

Is there any explanation of distance between Bhur lok (*earth*) and Indra lok? For example, I have seen Arjuna visits Indra lok to meet his father (*Indra*) while he and his brothers are in exile.

There might be some explanation about the distance in Hindu mythology. Please share it if it is available in any upanyas/book rather than just Mahabharatha.

Comment: 1609344000 kilometres is the distance of swarg loka from earth.

Comment: @Sanjay Please provide some valid references / citations. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indra lok is same as Swarg lok as Indra is considered the king of Swa lok or Swarga lok (heaven). As per Vishnu Puran, the distance between bhulok (earth) and swalok (heaven) would be 1 *lakh* *yojana* (8 lakh km).

It states, *surya mandala* (the zone of the sun) is situated 1 *lakh* *yojana* away from earth.

> *bhūmeryojanalakṣe tu sauraṃ maitreya manḍalam* [VP - 2.7.5]

And, from surya mandala onward the 14 *niyuta* *yojana* (approx. 1120 *lakh* km) till the Dhruva star is known as Swa loka:

> *dhruvasuryāntaraṃ yadya niyutāni caturdaśa
>
>      svarlokaḥ so'pi gadito lokasaṃsthānacintakaiḥ* [VP - 2.7.18]
>   **Meaning**
>   Those who analyze the position of different zones state the fourteen niyuta yojana between the sun and Dhruva as Swa loka.

So as per the scripture, basically after 8 *lakh* km from earth the region of swarga would begin.

Comment: Exactly in which direction we need to go to find region of swarga. coz Voyager 1 is 139 AU away from earth. Exactly 20,794,104,027.3 Kilometers.

Comment: You can't see Swarga Loka according to mythology.